# Make /posts/postId/ redirect to the post or have links to the revisions & timeline, instead of a 404

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, 404-not-found

While I was looking at the new feature I discovered (post timeline), I took a look at all the features that come with a post:

- See post [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35133777/revisions) using `https://stackoverflow.com/posts/PostId/revisions`;
- See post [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35133777/timeline) using `https://stackoverflow.com/posts/PostId/timeline`;
- (Maybe other features that I don't know about yet).

Given that, I'm a bit surprised that the URL `https://stackoverflow.com/posts/PostId/` leads to a 404 and I find it a bit misleading...

Shouldn't it redirect to the corresponding Q/A? Or indicate that the post exists and provide links to the features named above?

Comment: the `q/` and `a/` directories seem to automatically re-direct so I don't see why the `posts/` one can't do that also.

Comment: It might be a endpoint that is only accessible for moderators. I recall having asked that same question before somewhere in chat to a mod but I can't find it anymore and I forgot the answer...

Comment: @rene I don't believe that's the case.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyBanks now I will try to remember that ...

Comment: @MacroMan That would be sensible, but FWIW `q/`, `a/`, and `u/` exist *only* as redirects, they don't have any other purposes like `posts/...`.

Comment: @rene - it 404's for moderators too.,

Comment: Huh .. never about the "timeline" view, so thanks for that. Learn something new ...

Comment: @rene If it were an endpoint only for moderators, it would be a `401 NOT AUTHORIZED` not a `404 NOT FOUND`.

Comment: @corsiKa are you sure? I always thought that the team decided to return always 404 to not give away possible endpoints. On SE sites you should never get a 401 ...

Comment: @rene *if* they decided that, that's a poor decision. There is no "possible endpoint" that they should need to hide.

Comment: @corsiKa related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132892/how-should-we-handle-conditionally-broken-links

Comment: @MacroMan `/q/` and `/a/` are not directories; they're routes. In fact, almost all URLs you can see and touch on the site are routes and do not correspond to any real path structure. Thus, the main reason `/posts/$postId` 404s is simply that there's no route for it.